# Trying to push a React app to git fails because babel's package name is too big

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I am trying to push a React app I've been working on to git. I have never had this issue occur before, but apparently one of the babel packages is too big. This is the error I'm getting:

```
error: open("babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/option-assertions.js"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file 'babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/option-assertions.js'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Is it ok if I ignore this file? Why is the name so long that I can't push it to github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `git config core.longpaths true`. It will allow git to handle long filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Windows system, this may relate to a Windows restriction with length of the names in the system. Try to change record in register for Windows 10 to allow long pass:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
```

- Key: `LongPathsEnabled`
- Cange value from 0 to 1